# Bulk load to multiple HBase tables in single job

Tags: mapreduce, hbase

I want to bulk load data to mulitple tables using a single mapreduce job.Since the data volumes is high ,It would be time consuming to iterate through dataset twice and load using multiple jobs.Is there any way to do this ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Hbase. But i didnt need bulk load yet. But I came across this article which might help you.

http://hbase.apache.org/book/arch.bulk.load.html

The bulk load feature uses a MapReduce job to output table data in HBase's internal data format, and then directly loads the generated StoreFiles into a running cluster. Using bulk load will use less CPU and network resources than simply using the HBase API.

Comment: Yeah,I have already tried bulk loading using HFileOutFormat.I was wondering if it could be used to load data to multiple tables in single job ?. like using MultipleOutputs or something ?